# How restart a JBPM workflow which is completed

Tags: workflow, restart, jbpm

We are using JBPM 6 and we have a requirement to restart the same process once it is completed. Is there any way that we can restart the same process id without creating new one

Answer (score 0):

Restarting an already completed process instance makes not much sense as this would break with audit. At least I did not know a way to do this.

Consider to
a) start the Process again / create a new Process Instance with same input or
b) include a loop in your process that leads to the start of the Process model